# WordPress update not saving

Tags: widgets

I can't get the data saved and retrived in the edit form, Whats is wrong with following code:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Widgets;

class TextWidget extends \WP_Widget
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $widgetOpts = array(
            'classname' => 'widget_text',
            'description' => __('Um texto puro qualquer.'),
            'customize_selective_refresh' => true,
        );

        parent::__construct('custom_text', __('Texto puro'), $widgetOpts);
    }

    public static function init()
    {
        add_action('widgets_init', function() {
            register_widget(self::class);
        });
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        echo esc_html__($instance['content'], 'text_domain');
    }

    public function form($instance)
    {
        $instance = wp_parse_args(
            (array) $instance,
            ['content' => '']
        );
        ?>
        <p>
            <textarea 
                class="widefat" 
                id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('content')); ?>" 
                name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('content')); ?>" 
                type="text" 
                cols="30" 
                rows="10"
            ><?php echo esc_attr($instance['content']); ?></textarea>
        </p>
        <?php
    }

    public function update($newInstance, $oldInstance)
    {
        $instance = array();

        $instance['content'] = (!empty( $newInstance['content'])) ? $oldInstance['content'] : '';

        return $instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you call init?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
$instance['content'] = (!empty( $newInstance['content'])) ? $oldInstance['content'] : '';
```

This translates to:

```
if newinstance content is not empty and has something in it
    then use the old instance content
else if it is empty
    use ''
```

Should it not be using new instance instead of old?

For example, here's the example in the WP Codex docs:

```
/**
 * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::update()
 *
 * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
 * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
 *
 * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
 */
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();
    $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';

    return $instance;
}
```

So your save function does work after all, it's just saving the old value, not the new value